# Сортировка по столбцу "опережает" CellEndEdit в DataGridView

Tags: winforms, c#

Столкнулся с проблемой: если редактировать поле в DGV, по которому отсортирована таблица, то отредактированная строка меняет свое положение (сортировка срабатывает). Мне нужно после того, как я введу значение в строку, его обработать, а строка "убегает". Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавить в класс поле, хранящее последнюю измененную ячеку.
2. В обработчике CellBeginEdit запоминать ячеку.
3. В обработчике CellEndEdit обрабатывать ячейку, используя сохраненное значение.

Также можно проверить, когда срабатывают события CellParsing, CellStateChanged, - возможно, до сортировки.